# JACK audio sound altered on playback

Tags: c, libsndfile, jack

Here is an audio playback program using JACK that works but not properly. The glitch comes from audio data alteration while reading sound data from the file with sndfile, but i couldn't find why...The sound comes out but is ugly.

If you're familiar with soundfile and JACK audio kit it'll probably be a 5 min piece of cake for you otherwise it can be tricky.

If somebody has a clue or a suggestion : please feel free !

Here is my code that opens a wavfile using sndfile and play it whit JACK :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sndfile.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <jack/jack.h>
#include <jack/ringbuffer.h>

jack_port_t *input_port;
jack_port_t *output_port;
jack_client_t *client;
jack_ringbuffer_t *rb;
#define DEFAULT_RB_SIZE 16384  /*ringbuffer size in frames */
const size_t sample_size = sizeof(jack_default_audio_sample_t);

int
process (jack_nframes_t nframes, void *arg)
{
    jack_default_audio_sample_t *out;
    out = jack_port_get_buffer (output_port, nframes);

    for (int cpt =0; cpt < nframes; cpt++)
    {
        jack_ringbuffer_read (rb, (void *) &out[cpt], 4);
    }

    return 0;
}

void
jack_shutdown (void *arg)
{
    exit (1);
}

int main()
{
    SNDFILE *sf;
    SF_INFO info;
    int num_channels;
    int num, num_items;
    int *buf;
    int f,sr,c;
    int i,j;

    /* Open the WAV file. */
    info.format = 0;
    sf = sf_open("fileAudio.wav",SFM_READ,&info);
    if (sf == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to open the file.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    /* Print some of the info, and figure out how much data to read. */
    f = info.frames;
    sr = info.samplerate;
    c = info.channels;
    printf("frames=%d\n",f);
    printf("samplerate=%d\n",sr);
    printf("channels=%d\n",c);
    num_items = f*c;
    printf("num_items=%d\n",num_items);
    /* Allocate space for the data to be read, then read it. */
    buf = (int *) malloc(num_items*sizeof(int));
    num = sf_read_int(sf,buf,2250);//num_items);

/* Begin Jack setup */
const char **ports;
const char *client_name = "simple";
const char *server_name = NULL;
jack_options_t options = JackNullOption;
jack_status_t status;

rb = jack_ringbuffer_create(DEFAULT_RB_SIZE * sample_size);

/* Open a client connection to the JACK server */
client = jack_client_open (client_name, options, &status, server_name);
if (client == NULL) {
    fprintf (stderr, "jack_client_open() failed, "
        "status = 0x%2.0x\n", status);
    if (status & JackServerFailed) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Unable to connect to JACK server\n");
    }
    exit (1);
}
if (status & JackServerStarted) {
    fprintf (stderr, "JACK server started\n");
}
if (status & JackNameNotUnique) {
    client_name = jack_get_client_name(client);
    fprintf (stderr, "unique name `%s' assigned\n", client_name);
}

/* tell the JACK server to call `process()' whenever
   there is work to be done.*/
jack_set_process_callback (client, process, 0);

/* tell the JACK server to call 'jack_shutdown()' if
   it ever shuts down, either entirely, or if it
   just decides to stop calling us.*/
jack_on_shutdown (client, jack_shutdown, 0);

/* display the current sample rate. */
printf ("engine sample rate: %" PRIu32 "\n",
    jack_get_sample_rate (client));

/* create port */
output_port = jack_port_register (client, "output",
                JACK_DEFAULT_AUDIO_TYPE,
                JackPortIsOutput, 0);

if (output_port == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "no more JACK ports available\n");
    exit (1);
}

/* Tell the JACK server that we are ready to roll. Our
 * process() callback will start running now. */

if (jack_activate (client)) {
    fprintf (stderr, "cannot activate client");
    exit (1);
}

/* Connect the ports. You can't do this before the client is 
 * activated, because we can't make connectons to clients 
 * that aren't running. Note the confusing (but necessary)
 * orientation of the driver backend ports: playback ports are
 * "input" to the backend, and capture ports are "output" from it
 */
ports = jack_get_ports (client, NULL, NULL,
            JackPortIsPhysical|JackPortIsInput);
if (ports == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "no physical playback ports\n");
    exit (1);
}

if (jack_connect (client, jack_port_name (output_port), ports[0])) {
    fprintf (stderr, "cannot connect output ports\n");
}

free (ports);

/* keep running until stopped by the user */

while (1)
{
    if (jack_ringbuffer_write_space (rb) >= 4000)
    {
        jack_ringbuffer_write (rb, (char*) buf, 4000);
        sf_read_int(sf, buf, 1000);
    }
}

/* this is never reached but if the program 
   had some other way to exit besides deing killed,
   they woud be important to call.*/

jack_client_close (client);
exit (0);
}
```

Comment: With `num = sf_read_int(sf,buf,2250);` you are reading the first 2250 items instead of the whole.

Comment: @Bebs, Hi thank you for replying ! There is a while loop at the very end that load the jack_ring_buffer; so I can hear the whole track but the sound is altered.